# Missing header when building CocoaPods project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I `pod install` NYXImagesKit to my example project, it builds successfully but after the simulator lunches, there is error in `Xcode`:
`/XXX.m:17:9: 'NYXImagesKit.h' file not found`

Everything is fine, the simulator works fine, the only problem is that the build error is there but no link error, it is very strange.

I have `${PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}` defined in `HEADER SEARCH PATH`, and the pod.config is as follow:

```
ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = ${PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS} $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -lxml2 -framework Accelerate -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreImage -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore
PODS_BUILD_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders" "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/NYXImagesKit" "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/hpple"
PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = ${PODS_PUBLIC_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}
PODS_PUBLIC_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/NYXImagesKit" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/hpple"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised the simulator launches if it's showing you a build issue. You might want to try cleaning your project from Product -> Clean in the menu bar. Or deleting your derived data from the Organizer. Also verify that CocoaPods has the newest version with `pod --version` (right now it is 0.21.0) otherwise update with `[sudo] gem update`

Comment: i have done all of above but i still got the problem, it is ok to build, and run, but the red alert indicated the File not found always there...my pods version is 0.20.2

Comment: @zolibra not exactly sure what the issue is but you should update CocoaPods with the command above. They develop it super quickly.